# How do I remove mildew from walls and ceilings?

Tags: bathroom, walls, cleaning

My bathroom has some mildew on the walls and ceilings, and I desperately want to get rid of it. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill a spray bottle with one part bleach, 9 parts water.  Wear gloves and then spray the walls with the solution, let sit for a minute and then wipe with the sponge.